# only allow access to a some pages on my site from a specific type of URL .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I run a video site, and I have lots of videos. My users have requested the "Youtube unlisted" feature. So I when about to try to create it and I am almost done.

**This is what I have done so far.**

1) Created a secret key which I defined as `secret_key = md5(uniqid($VID)).$VID;`

2) Allowed the MySQL field `secret_key` to be updated by the user.

What I am hoping to achieve is to add some instructions in the `.htaccess` for all videos set to be private. That will only allow users that have access to a private video from a specific link to be able to view the video.

So the link is in the form `$baseurl.$secret_key`. This link will never clash because the VID is different for every video.

**What instructions** can I add in my **`.htaccess`** file to only allow videos that are set to private to **only be accessible via a specific link.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to hack something together using URL rewriting, redirecting the user to an error page if the key does not match. However, .htaccess files are not designed for dynamic updates like this.

The easiest solution would be to change the names of the files to incorporate the keys, and rename a file whenever its secret key is changed.

The preferred solution would be to make use of whichever server-side scripting language is already in use to block requests based on the result of a database lookup.

Comment: Thanks quantumbadger... I managed to do it by simply using the $_GET to get the value of the secret key from the url and perform some tests to see if the value enters exists in the database... If it does then the video is was shown to the user.